# MySQL UPDATE, MAX, JOIN query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: -

```
manu_table
product_id, manufacturer
1, ford
2, ford
3, toyota

product_table
product_id, score
1, 80
2, 60
3, 40
```

I'd like to store the top scoring product_id for each manufacturer in a summary table: -

```
summary_table
manufacturer, max_score
ford,   1
toyota, 3
```

So far I've got: -

```
UPDATE summary_table st
SET max_score = (
                 SELECT product_id 
                 FROM (
                       SELECT manufacturer, product_id, max(score) as ms 
                       FROM manu_table 
                       LEFT JOIN product_table USING (product_id) 
                       group by product_id) t)
WHERE st.manufacturer = manu_table.manufacturer;
```

Having troubles...All help is appreciated greatly.

Comment: What troubles are you having?

Comment: are you getting an error? what is the output from your current query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand the problem I think this would work, I have used `MAX(Product_ID)` just to resolve any duplicates, where 2 products for the same manufacture might have the same score and both be the highest score. You may want to resolve duplicates differently.

```
UPDATE  summary_table
SET     max_score = 
        (   SELECT  MAX(m.Product_ID) [MaxScoreProductID] 
            FROM    manu_table m
                    INNER JOIN product_table p
                        ON m.Product_ID = p.Product_ID
                    INNER JOIN
                    (   SELECT  Manufacturer, MAX(Score) [MaxScore]
                        FROM    manu_table m
                                LEFT JOIN product_table p
                                    ON m.Product_ID = p.Product_ID
                        GROUP BY Manufacturer
                    ) ms
                        ON ms.Manufacturer = m.Manufacturer
                        AND ms.MaxScore = p.Score
            WHERE   m.Manufacturer = summary_table.Manufacturer
            GROUP BY m.Manufacturer
        )
```

Comment: This works but will take 29 days to process 11 million rows in product_table. Any thoughts on a quicker method?

Comment: Is it indexed properly? Even on 11 million rows this should run fairly quickly. I'd question the need for a summary table, a summary View would be better, would not require regular updates, and should maintain indexes. Unfortunately I have done very little work with MySQL and only really work with SQL Server so my advice is probably not the most appropriate. Sorry.

Comment: Yes there was a missing index (product_table.Score), it will still take a few hours, when you say fairly quickly is this what you mean?

Comment: It is not really what I meant, I'd expect the above querie to take at most 1 hour. Bear in mind that foreign keys are not indicies, so it may be necessary to create indicies along with your keys, realistically I'd expect an update this simple on 11 million rows to take seconds, maybe minutes, but certaily not hours

Answer (score 4):

This query sets product_id for max score:

```
UPDATE summary_table st
  JOIN (SELECT t1.* FROM 
  (SELECT mt.*, pt.score FROM manu_table mt JOIN product_table pt ON mt.product_id = pt.product_id) t1
  JOIN (
    SELECT mt.manufacturer, MAX(pt.score) max_score FROM manu_table mt
     JOIN product_table pt
       ON mt.product_id = pt.product_id
     GROUP BY mt.manufacturer
  ) t2
  ON t1.manufacturer = t2.manufacturer AND t1.score = t2.max_score
  ) t
  ON t.manufacturer = st.manufacturer
SET st.max_score = t.product_id
```